# STM32 uart interrupt not firing

Tags: stm32, uart, interrupts

After having a UART echo working on my nucleo F446ze, I am trying to get UART interrupts working.

I thought all I had to do is :

- set the priority for the UART3 interrupt
- enable the USART3_IRQn
- implement the weak functions (`USART3_IRQHandler`, and `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback`)

But no data is being received, the interrupt callback never fires.

Main.cpp :

```
extern "C" {
    #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
    #include "stm32f446xx.h"
}

static UART_HandleTypeDef s_UARTHandle;
static bool uart2HasReceivedData;

static uint32_t start;
 
void ConfigureLedGpio()
{
    __GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioLed;
    gpioLed.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_7 | GPIO_PIN_14 | GPIO_PIN_8;
    gpioLed.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    gpioLed.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    gpioLed.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpioLed);
}

void ConfigureUart3Gpio()
{
    __GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioUart;
    gpioUart.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8 | GPIO_PIN_9;
    gpioUart.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    gpioUart.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART3;
    gpioUart.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    gpioUart.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &gpioUart);
}

void ConfigureUart3()
{
    __HAL_RCC_USART3_CLK_ENABLE();

    s_UARTHandle.Instance        = USART3;
    s_UARTHandle.Init.BaudRate   = 115200;
    s_UARTHandle.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    s_UARTHandle.Init.StopBits   = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    s_UARTHandle.Init.Parity     = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    s_UARTHandle.Init.HwFlowCtl  = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    s_UARTHandle.Init.Mode       = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    
    HAL_UART_Init(&s_UARTHandle);

    // Give USART3 interrupt priority and enable it
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART3_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART3_IRQn);
}

int main()
{
    HAL_Init();
 
    ConfigureLedGpio();
    ConfigureUart3Gpio();
    ConfigureUart3();

    uint8_t receivedByte = 0;
        
    start = HAL_GetTick();

    // Trigger the hall that I am expecting data
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&s_UARTHandle, &receivedByte, 1);

    while(1)
    {
        // Blink LED: Easy check to keep track that the program is still running
        if (HAL_GetTick() - start > 100)
        {
            GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_PIN_0;
            start = HAL_GetTick();
        }

        if(uart2HasReceivedData) 
        {
            uart2HasReceivedData = false;

            /**
             * Blocking read/write, this works, so I think proof that the configuration for gpio and uart are correct (?)
             * 
             * HAL_UART_Receive(&s_UARTHandle, &receivedByte, sizeof(uint8_t), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
             * HAL_UART_Transmit(&s_UARTHandle, &receivedByte, sizeof(uint8_t), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
             */

            // Trigger HAL that I am expecting data again
            HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&s_UARTHandle, &receivedByte, 1);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Below the C interupt handlers
 * Must be implemented, otherwise the weak implementation will go into infinte loop and hang up the app
 * Must delcare as extern "C" otherwise cpp linker won't match it with weak defined function (which results 
 * in the same behavior, infinite loop -> app hung up)
 */

extern "C" void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *UartHandle) {
    uart2HasReceivedData = true;
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_7 | GPIO_PIN_14;
}

extern "C" void USART3_IRQHandler()
{
    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&s_UARTHandle);
    GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_7 | GPIO_PIN_14;
}

extern "C" void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    HAL_IncTick();
    HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();
}
```

What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: How are you observing it does nothing? By using a debugger? With an oscilloscope? Or looking at the LEDs that turn on for a microsecond for each byte?

Comment: Hi Just me, yes the latter. I am sending the character 'a' from my pc. So I don't expect it to fire every micro second. I expect it to fire once every time I click the button send from my pc

Comment: Also added a debugger, and put breakpoints in the interrupt callbacks, they never hit. I am doing something wrong in code. Hope somebody can help me further

Comment: @bas Did you enable reception interrupts by the instruction `s_UARTHandle.Instance->->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE;`? See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75384204/how-to-modify-st-example-uart-hyperterminal-it-to-enable-uart-receive-interrupt/75399967#75399967) for more huge answer.